# Webpage Icon on Desktop and Notification Badge

Tags: web, icons, desktop-application, desktop

We have a web portal and our client have a requirement of keeping the webpage icon on the desktop that part was as easy as keeping and shortcut with icon which points to Webpage, however they also want to have dynamic notification badge on the icon something similar to below one -

[image: Icon With Notification Badge]

This notification badge will keep changing based on number of action items, I couldn't figure out how to solve this without having an full fledge desktop application any pointer or help would be greatly appreciated.